# Is (Non RGB) Xtion Pro Supported?

Tags: ros, openni, ros-hydro, xtion, asus-xtion-pro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have an Xtion Pro Sensor (non 'Pro-Live' version, *without* RGB camera) and am trying to run:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

It dies immediately with with 'Service Call Failed!' errors.

I'm running Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. Before I start delving into messing with parameters, wondering if *anyone* has managed to get the non-rgb Xtion Pro depth camera running with the openni_camera package? Or is it simply not supported?

(I also have a the Pro-Live RGB version of the sensor and it works fine on the same system)

**EDIT**:
The underlying problem was a symbol lookup error which I solved by updating my system.  Now I'm running openni2_launch and the camera *is* recognized, but I'm getting this error on launch:

```
[ERROR] [1409344784.275581907]: Unsupported color video mode - Resolution: 640x480@30Hz Format: RGB888
```

and this error when I add a PointCloud2 pointing to /camera/depth/points in Rviz:

```
[ INFO] [1409345247.761731749]: Starting depth stream.
[ INFO] [1409345248.232848173]: using default calibration URL
[ INFO] [1409345248.233537814]: camera calibration URL: file:///home/skyzorg/.ros/camera_info/depth_PS1080_PrimeSense.yaml
[ INFO] [1409345248.234404179]: Unable to open camera calibration file [/home/skyzorg/.ros/camera_info/depth_PS1080_PrimeSense.yaml]
[ WARN] [1409345248.235351909]: Camera calibration file /home/skyzorg/.ros/camera_info/depth_PS1080_PrimeSense.yaml not found.
[ERROR] [1409345248.237372380]: Rectified topic '/camera/depth/image_rect_raw' requested but camera publishing '/camera/depth/camera_info' is uncalibrated
```

I can't find any easy parameter change fix in the openni2.launch file, do I actually have to calibrate the camera? My Xtion Pro Live RGBD camera gives the same calibration warnings but not the last error shown above

---

**EDIT2:**
Couldn't get non RGB Xtion Pro working under Xubuntu 12.04 and Hyrdo, I may have been running into this bug, as the error messages match exactly:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_camera/issues/14

But a fresh of install of Xubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo did the trick, `openni2_launch` just works, with default settings.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191498/is-(non-rgb)-xtion-pro-supported?/) by [skyzorg](https://answers.ros.org/users/20102/skyzorg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There shouldn't be any issues using the Xtion Pro. Can you update your question with output from `lsusb -v`, and relevant parts of `dmesg` when you plug in the sensor, and when you start openni? Keep in mind that newer ASUS sensors work with openni2 packages instead of openni.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skyzorg](https://answers.ros.org/users/20102/skyzorg/) on 2014-08-29**:
Thanks! You've answered my basic compatibility question but I'm now I'm getting a calibration error, please see update to the question

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-02**:
I've only ever used the live version, and never had that issue, so I can't help you there. You could try running the [calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/MonocularCalibration) yourself and see if that helps.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-02**:
oh and try disabling the `rgb_processing` argument in `openni2_launch`, see if that gets rid of your error.

**Comment by [skyzorg](https://answers.ros.org/users/20102/skyzorg/) on 2014-09-11**:
tried everything short of actually calibrating in xubuntu 12.04 + hydro, nothing worked. BUT SUCCESS! >> after a fresh install of xubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo, `openni2_launch` just works!

**Comment by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on 2016-02-05**:
short of upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo (I am hoping to stay with Hydro on 12.04), has anyone found a solution?